Repositioning Text and Icon in Row
I want to change the position of my icon so it's not in line with the text, just want to shift it a bit.
This is the code that I have created, please check it.
Bubble(
            margin: BubbleEdges.only(top: 10),
            alignment: Alignment.topRight,
            nip: BubbleNip.rightTop,
            color: Color.fromRGBO(225, 255, 199, 1.0),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                Text('Bang kuy, adu bola sama rt beside'),
                Text("16:55",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10.0),),
                Icon(Icons.done_all, size: 15.0,)
              ],
            )
          ),

this is the result

I want to make it a little lower, but don't want to make the bubble bigger.
like this


You can wrap with top padding for the timeStamp. also checkout RichText

thank you, it help so much for me @Md.YeasinSheikh

you are welcome,  happy coding, also you can find more on flutter/layout

You could do it like this, or try something else with an expanded in order to align the text and icon on the bottom. What you could also do is Wrap the first widget in a expanded and set the alignment of row to this:
crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end
Bubble(
  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
  alignment: Alignment.topRight,
  nip: BubbleNip.rightTop,
  color: Color.fromRGBO(225, 255, 199, 1.0
  child: Row(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    children: [
      Text('Bang kuy, adu bola sama rt beside'),
      SizedBox(width: 8),
      Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
        children: [
          Text(
            "16:55",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10.0),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 2),
          Icon(
            Icons.done_all,
            size: 15.0,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ],
  ),
)


